# Proof that different ways of approaching Green's Function gives the same answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning about Green's function, and the different ways of obtaining it, through variation of parameters and through eigenfunction expansion.

Variation of parameters gives it via one equation for a < x < t and another for t< x< b, in this form: [Variation of Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WclsA.png)

Eigenfunction expansion gives it in the form of [Eigenfunction Expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf58c.png)

I was wondering if there was any way of proving these forms are essentially equivalent?

I was thinking along the lines of expanding variation of parameters as a series, and showing that the Cks match for each series. However I am unsure as of how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to showing that

$$A_k = \frac{1}{\lambda_kn_k}y_k(t)$$
where $n_k = \langle y_k,y_k \rangle$,
is equal to
$$B_k = \frac{\int^b_a g(x,t)y_k}{\int^b_a y_k^2} = \frac{\int^b_a g(x,t)y_k}{n_k}$$

but
$$\frac{1}{\lambda_k}\int^b_a \lambda_kg(x,t)y_k = \frac{1}{\lambda_k}\langle g(x,t),Ly_k \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda_k}\langle Lg(x,t),y_k \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda_k}\langle \delta(x-t),y_k \rangle = \frac{1}{\lambda_k}y_k(t)$$

so

$$B_k = A_k$$